# C++ negative byte value

Tags: c++

I have c++ code that read 16 byte from a file as char value
And I have a table of unsigned char from 0 to 255
I want to use byte values from file as a index in my unsigned char table to change the original file byte values but I get negative value from file and as you know you can't use negative value as a index in array
What should I do ?

Edit

```
const unsigned char TopSbox[256] = {
    0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76,
    0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0,
    0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15,
    0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75,
    0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84,
    0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf,
    0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8,
    0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2,
    0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73,
    0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb,
    0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79,
    0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08,
    0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a,
    0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e,
    0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf,
    0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16
};

void RunFunction(){

    ifstream reader;
    ofstream writer;

    reader.open(myfile_address, ifstream::binary);
    writer.open(storage_file,ofstream::out);

    unsigned int BufferSize =16;

    char *Transform_Buffer = new char[BufferSize];

    reader.read(Transform_Buffer, BufferSize);
    ExchangeData(Transform_Buffer, BufferSize);
    writer.write(Transform_Buffer, BufferSize);
    writer.flush();
}

void EData::ExchangeData(char data[], const unsigned int size){
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        data[i] = TopSbox[data[i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a pointer to `table + 128` as the base of your indexing.

Comment: Add code here to show how are you reading from file and also first 16bytes from file.

Comment: Read `unsigned char` instead of `char` or `static_cast` `char` to `unsigned char`.

Comment: You can't read unsigned char from ifstream.read  function only takes char * but I test static cast now

Comment: Remember that `char`, `signed char` and  `unsigned char` all share the internal representation, but differ in their interpretation, in particular, in how they are cast onto integer types, like `int`. This is why `ifstream.read`  has an interface for `char` only. All others are easily achieved by proper casting or using pointers to the desired type, e.g. `unsigned char * ptr`. You can have a buffer of `unsigned char`s and pass it via a pointer to `char`s.

Comment: Please decide - either pascal case or snake case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `operator new` unless absolutely necessary.
Rather than

```
    char *Transform_Buffer = new char[BufferSize];
```

you can define the buffer as a local array:

```
    const unsigned int BufferSize = 16;
    unsigned char Transform_Buffer[BufferSize];
```

For this to work, you should declare `BufferSize` as `const`. Notice also that I declared the elements of the buffer as `unsigned char`.

Then, this line

```
reader.read(Transform_Buffer, BufferSize);
```

can be replaced with

```
reader.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(Transform_Buffer), BufferSize);
```

and similarly for `writer`.

Please also replace all `char*` in function declarations with `unsigned char*`, eg:

```
void EData::ExchangeData(unsigned char data[], const unsigned int size){
```

I guess everything should work as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

Just have buffer of `unsigned char`s. Then pass it as `char*`  to `ifstream::read`. Let's say `char*` works kind of like a generic pointer.

You may want to prefer to use standard containers.

```
    std::vector<unsigned char> transform_buffer(buffer_size);
    reader.read(static_cast<char*>(transform_buffer.data()), transform_buffer.size());
    exchange_data(transform_buffer);
}

void exchange_data(std::vector<unsigned char>& transform_buffer) {
   for (auto&& i : transform_buffer) {
       i = TopSbox[i];
    }
}
```